# A whole example for Retrofit- a beginners guide

Tags: java, php, android, retrofit

If you read through this question you'll know how beginner I am at using `Retrofit`. Indeed my aim is to upload a video file using `Retrofit`, but for now, I just want to start using it in the simplest way. Now I want to design a very very simple login mechanism. After reading many posts, blogs, and suchlike that implicitly assume you already know many things all I know is what I have presented below.
 **I know** that there are many tutorials out there but believe me if I knew how to put them altogether I wouldn't ask this question. Unfortunately, there is nothing like [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) for `Retrofit` to help you understand every other thing.

**`login.php`**

```
<?php
//should this page be placed at /api/login.php ?
$response = array("error" => false);
if ( isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['passwordk']) )
{
    //take the required actions. not important at all in this question
    echo json_encode($response);//(1)Does this provide the responce for my app?
}
else
{
    $response["error"] = true;
    $response["error_msg"] = "User with the provided info not found!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

**`ApiService.java`:**

```
public interface ApiService 
{ 
    @GET("/api/Login")//(2)Is this correct?
    public void getDummieContent(Callback<Something> callback);//(3)What should Something be?

}
```

**`RestClient.java`:**

```
public class RestClient
{
    //What should this do?
}
```

**`LoginActivity.java`:**

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity
{
    //How to use the other things here to do login?
}
```

Please, help me complete this simple task. I think it will be a great starting point for many other people struggling to learn about Retrofit.

Comment: Dear friend who have voted to close this question, I promise many people cannot solve even this simple issue. So, please stop turning SO to a hell, and let people learn!

Comment: `ApiService` seems to be OK. In `RestClient` you are supposed to have restadapter instance with using `ApiService` interface, and method that will wrap `ApiService` interface methods. `Something` stands for class in which response will be deserialized

Comment: @404notfound So something class should be something like: `public class User { String username, password;} ?`

Comment: If server response contains json with username and password fields, then yes.

Comment: Ok, I guess it could be a part of the answer. +1 :)

Comment: In a few minutes I will post more code example which will help you.

Comment: @404notfound God bless you.

Answer (score 1):

`RestClient.java`
Should be something like

```
public class RestClient{

private final ApiService restApi;

private RestClient() {
        final RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(Network.API_ADDRESS)
                .setClient(new OkClient(client));

        restApi = builder.build().create(RestApi.class);
}

public static void login(Callback<Something> callback){
    RestClient client = new RestClient();
    client.getApi().getDummieContent(callback);
}

public ApiService getApi()
{
    return restApi;
}
}
```

and now in Activity/Fragment or whatever  you want you can use it as below 
`RestClient.login(callback)`;

I am writing this in notepad without IDE, so it is possible that this code contains minor errors. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your useful post. Would you please say what should be the url of my page? I mean should it be something like `api/login.php`?

Comment: I am not sure, so I just give you an example. If `http://www.google.com/login` is your api address then you should pass `http://www.google.com` as endpoint in `RestAdapter Builder` and `/login` in `ApiService` method annotation

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to, first, set the server side up and running.

Test it with a [REST client](http://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop/).

Then, and only then, just follow any Retrofit tutorial, like [this one](http://themakeinfo.com/2015/04/retrofit-android-tutorial/) for example.

Comment: I have experience working with volley. Indeed I can do this an a lot more with volley. My problem is the client side. I have already seen that tutorial but I couldn't run it. Please compare it with the tutorial I mentioned.

Comment: @mok for your question, I though you were looking for info in how to set up server and client for working with Retrofit. My point was that the use of Retrofit shouldn't be coupled with the server implementation.

Comment: Thank you for taking time but I guess now you know what I meant.